# C++ Code Analysis - how to add custom dictionary?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

;) Yeah. I also have C++ in my solution.

How do I add a custom dictionary there? There is no tool for an includes file, as well as no way to tell it the type is CustomDictionary.

THe advice and approach shown in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188(v=VS.100).aspx is not usable for C++ projects.

Comment: Can you please tell what you mean by CustomDictionary? I have no idea on it.

Comment: A custom dictionary of known terms for the spell checker, you know. A XML file with known words. If you would bother checking the link in the question more information would be at your fingertips.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For VS2010, you can set the dictionary by editing your .vcxproj file and pasting this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <CodeAnalysisDictionary Include="c:\temp\mydictionary.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Modify the path to your dictionary.

To make this a permanent setting for all your C++ projects, navigate to c:\program files\msbuild\microsoft.cpp\v4.0 and edit Microsoft.Cpp.props, pasting the above (make a backup please).

To verify that the change is effective, use Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run, MSBuild project build log file verbosity = Diagnostic.  Rebuild your project, look in the .log file and verify that fxcopcmd.exe got started with the /dictionary option.

Both approaches worked well on my machine.

Comment: Could you add - how do I reference the project directory in there? I do not want a full path, thanks to continous integration building in a separate path.

Comment: and - I just add a complete itemgroup?

Answer (score 6):

To get a CustomDictionary working with C++ you will have to edit the project file manually as described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/859956e5-79f2-49b2-80a6-135beefb4991).

Comment: Yes, thus my downvode - sorry.